# List not aligning/centering horizontally

Tags: css

I'm having trouble centering these buttons on a page. I just know it's something stupid I missed, but I can't figure out what. Here's the page:

```
<div id="page1">
    <ul id="choiceBtns">
        <li>All Time</li>
        <li>Last 2 Weeks</li>
        <li>Last Year</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#choiceBtns li{
    display:inline !important;
    border:solid;
    padding:3px;
}

#choiceBtns {
    margin:10px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by modifying the CSS as follows:

```
#choiceBtns {
    margin:10px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Since your `li` child elements are `inline`, they will center within the width of the parent block, which in your case, is also the width of the page.

You may get slightly better control if you apply `display: inline-block` to the `li` elements if you need to add vertical padding and so on.

Finally, you don't need the `!important` declaration.